# How to load config file in python from an external module

Tags: python, flask

I have a config module (myConfig.py) present in a library for which i created a standard distribution package using setuptools.

```
  --configPackage
    |
    | ---- myConfig.py
    | ---- __init__.py
```

myConfig.py is a key value pair like this:

```
MY_NAME = 'myname'
MY_AGE = '99'
```

Now I have another python project where I import this config module like this

```
import configPackage.myConfig as customConfig
```

If this config file was native to my python project and had not come from an external project then I would have done something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config.from_object('app.configPackage.config')
```

where config is actually config.py file under configPackage.

and any key value pair in config.py could then be accessed as

```
 myName = app.config['MY_NAME']
```

My problem is that I am not able to load the external config file in the above mentioned way for a native config file. What I have tried is this which doesn't work:

```
import configPackage.myConfig as customConfig

app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config.from_object(customConfig)
myName = app.config['MY_NAME']
```

I get the following error

model_name =  app.config['model_name']
KeyError: 'model_name'

Which means that it is not able to load the config file from external module correctly. Can anyone tell me the right way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Have you tried ```app.config.from_object('configPackage.myConfig')```

Comment: yes i did and it says module has no attribute myConfig. Also I do see configPackage filer in site_packages folder in my local python34 installation under which i see myConfig python file. Not sure why it can't load it

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you place your config entries in the ```__init__.py``` of ```configPackage``` and try ```app.config.from_object('configPackage')```

Comment: tried but same key error. it loads bunch of properties as i can see when i hover my mouse on app.config, just not the ones that i have define.

Comment: basically it just loads the flask configuration and not the ones that I want it to load from an external module

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

in your `__init__.py` of configPackage import myConfig as shown below

```
import configPackage.myConfig as myConfig
```

And in your other app try

```
app.config.from_object('configPackage.myConfig')
```

Comment: But module loads ?

Comment: Can you do an import like below in a python prompt and inspect the module for your config entries ?

```from configPackage import myConfig

print myConfig.MY_AGE```

Comment: Looks like you are getting error for the key ```model_name``` is it in your ```configPackage.myConfig``` ?

Comment: on python prompt, it says invalid syntax on myConfig.MY_AGE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144495/discussion-between-hary-and-gipsy).

Comment: based on your last comment to try stuff on python prompt, I got it working. Worked on both python prompt and in pydev as well.  from configPackage import myConfig. Then myconfig.my_age, myconfig.my_name. If you edit your solution above based on your last comment, I will go ahead and mark it as the right and accepted answer. thanks again